# Sql aggregate count = 0

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, scope, arel

I have the following models in a Rails 3 app, and select requirement:

`class Item < AR

 has_many :holdings`

`class Holding < AR

belongs_to :item`

The Holding model has an 'active' boolean value.

I wish to find each Item that has 0 'active' holdings ( it may have any number of associated holdings ), I've tried quite a few combinations.

`SELECT * from items JOIN

(SELECT holdings.item_id, count(ifnull(item_id,0)) AS hcount FROM holdings

WHERE holdings.active = "t"

GROUP BY holdings.item_id

HAVING hcount = 0)

ON items.id = holdings.item_id`

but this will only return counts that are greater than 0.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use count when you mean any!

Use an not exists clause.

```
SELECT * from items i
where not exists(select holdings.item_id 
             from holdings 
             where holdings.active = 't' 
               and holdings.item_id = i.item_id)
```

This statement in english says give me all the rows from items where there are no matching rows in holdings.